# Add a vertical line centered inside a framebox

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, framed

I would like to have a vertical line inside my framebox. So my framebox should be divided into two equal halves. I haven't found anything about it in the forum yet. Here is a code snippet.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\def\restofpage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}

\begin{document}

\framebox[\textwidth]{\parbox{\textwidth}{
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X|X}
 text & some more text \\
&\\
&\\
&\\
\end{xltabular}
\par\vspace{\restofpage}}}

\end{document}
```

I first tried xltabular, but then the line doesn't start and end exactly at the top and bottom box lines respectively. Here is the output

[image]

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards